# If-else Statement with drop-down list

Tags: html, if-statement

I am doing a Sign Up page. So, there is a drop-down list where users are to choose whether they are a student, staff or guest. If Student is chosen, they need to key in their Admin Number. For Staffs, Staff ID and for Guest its NRIC.

May I know how to do so?

[image]

Comment: newbie - please add your code instead of providing an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you're looking for.

Keep in mind, this was done with the assistance of the jQuery library, so you will need to include that into your code.

Also, for further reference, when making a post, make sure to include your code as I did below instead of an image.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.group').hide();
  $('#student').show();
  $('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
  })
$("input[placeholder]").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('size', $(this).attr('placeholder').length);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectMe">
  <option value="student">Student</option>
  <option value="staff">Staff</option>
  <option value="guest">Guest</option>
</select>
<div id="student" class="group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your Admin Number">
</div>
<div id="staff" class="group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your Staff ID">
</div>
<div id="guest" class="group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your NRIC">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, noted! For the first set of codes, where do I place it at (app.js/ controllers.js)? I am actually using brackets fyi..

Comment: @newbie123 You could simply put it in `<script></script>` tags at the bottom of the page containing your form, right before the closing `</body>` tag. If I helped you, be sure to mark my answer as acceptable by clicking the checkmark.